# Click label to add class to current target and remove from any other (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 forms, where I have input type="radio" to select one plan. What I expect to accomplish is to click on label of any plan from these 3 forms, make current clicked label target radio active, and move the position of the of "range slider" to necessary plan chosen.
My biggest problem is that I don't understand, how to add class to current item that I would click and remove it from all others? Please could someone give a clue?

Here is the code snippet.

```js
var selectPlanLabel = document.querySelectorAll('.select-plan__radio');
for (var i = 0; i < selectPlanLabel.length; i++) {
    selectPlanLabel[i].addEventListener('click', changeRadio.bind(null, i));
}

function changeRadio(selected, e) {
    var planLabelActive = document.querySelectorAll('.select-plan__label--active');
    for (var i = 0; i < planLabelActive.length; i++) {
        planLabelActive[i].classList.remove('select-plan__label--active');
    }
    e.target.classList.add('select-plan__label--active');
}
```

```css
.container {
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.visually-hidden {
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 1px;
}

.select-plan {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.spacer {
    width: 100%;
}

.spacer-gap--16 {
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.spacer-gap--30 {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.select-plan__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}
.select-plan__radio, .select-plan__label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select-plan__label {
    z-index: 10;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.select-plan__radio {
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.dimensional-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.select-plan__range-slider {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0.820721px 3.28288px rgba(37, 71, 122, 0.25);
    z-index: 1;
}

.select-plan__range-slider::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    top: calc(30% - 10px);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4376A6;
    box-shadow: -0.820721px 0.820721px 1.64144px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <form class="select-plan" action="">
            <div class="select-plan__container">
                <div class="select-plan__range-slider"></div>
                <div class="dimensional-container">
                    <div class="spacer spacer-gap--30"></div>
                    <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="one-month" id="select-month">
                    <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-month">1 month</label>
                </div>
                <div class="dimensional-container">
                    <div class="spacer spacer-gap--30"></div>
                    <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="three-months" id="select-three-month" checked>
                    <label class="select-plan__label select-plan__label--active" for="select-three-month">3 month</label>
                </div>
                <div class="dimensional-container">
                    <div class="spacer spacer-gap--30"></div>
                    <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="twelve-months" id="select-twelve-month">
                    <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-twelve-month">12 month</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer spacer-gap--16"></div>
            <button class="select-plan__submit" type="submit">Try now</button>
        </form>
        <form class="select-plan" action="">
            <div class="select-plan__container">
                <div class="select-plan__range-slider"></div>
                <div class="dimensional-container">
                    <div class="spacer spacer-gap--30"></div>
                    <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="one-month" id="select-month">
                    <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-month">1 month</label>
                </div>
                <div class="dimensional-container">
                    <div class="spacer spacer-gap--30"></div>
                    <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="three-months" id="select-three-month" checked>
                    <label class="select-plan__label select-plan__label--active" for="select-three-month">3 month</label>
                </div>
                <div class="dimensional-container">
                    <div class="spacer spacer-gap--30"></div>
                    <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="twelve-months" id="select-twelve-month">
                    <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-twelve-month">12 month</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer spacer-gap--16"></div>
            <button class="select-plan__submit" type="submit">Try now</button>
        </form>
        <form class="select-plan" action="">
            <div class="select-plan__container">
                <div class="select-plan__range-slider"></div>
                <div class="dimensional-container">
                    <div class="spacer spacer-gap--30"></div>
                    <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="one-month" id="select-month">
                    <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-month">1 month</label>
                </div>
                <div class="dimensional-container">
                    <div class="spacer spacer-gap--30"></div>
                    <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="three-months" id="select-three-month" checked>
                    <label class="select-plan__label select-plan__label--active" for="select-three-month">3 month</label>
                </div>
                <div class="dimensional-container">
                    <div class="spacer spacer-gap--30"></div>
                    <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="twelve-months" id="select-twelve-month">
                    <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-twelve-month">12 month</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer spacer-gap--16"></div>
            <button class="select-plan__submit" type="submit">Try now</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any JavaScript, can you share your JavaScript?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi sorry, probably forgot to attach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS by moving the slider indicator to each radio rather having it based on the slider bar.

change

```
.select-plan__range-slider::after
```

to

```
input.select-plan__radio[type="radio"]:checked+label::before
```

You'll need to fine-tune the spacing.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.visually-hidden {
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 1px;
}

.select-plan {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.spacer {
    width: 100%;
}

.spacer-gap--16 {
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}


.select-plan__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}
.select-plan__radio, .select-plan__label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select-plan__label {
    z-index: 10;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: block;
    height: 48px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.select-plan__radio {
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.dimensional-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.select-plan__range-slider {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0.820721px 3.28288px rgba(37, 71, 122, 0.25);
    z-index: 1;
}

.select-plan__radio[type="radio"]:checked+label::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    top: calc(30% - 10px);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4376A6;
    box-shadow: -0.820721px 0.820721px 1.64144px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    z-index: 1;
}

.select-plan__radio[value="one-month"]:checked+label::before {
left: 0%;
background: lightgray;
}
.select-plan__radio[value="three-months"]:checked+label::before {
left: 46.5%;
background: pink;
}
.select-plan__radio[value="twelve-months"]:checked+label::before {
left: 95%;
background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="select-plan" action="">
      <div class="select-plan__container">
          <div class="select-plan__range-slider"></div>
          <div class="dimensional-container">
              <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="one-month" id="select-month">
              <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-month">1 month</label>
          </div>
          <div class="dimensional-container">
              <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="three-months" id="select-three-month" checked>
              <label class="select-plan__label select-plan__label--active" for="select-three-month">3 month</label>
          </div>
          <div class="dimensional-container">
              <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="twelve-months" id="select-twelve-month">
              <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-twelve-month">12 month</label>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer spacer-gap--16"></div>
      <button class="select-plan__submit" type="submit">Try now</button>
  </form>
  <form class="select-plan" action="">
      <div class="select-plan__container">
          <div class="select-plan__range-slider"></div>
          <div class="dimensional-container">
              <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="one-month" id="select-month2">
              <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-month2">1 month</label>
          </div>
          <div class="dimensional-container">
              <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="three-months" id="select-three-month2" checked>
              <label class="select-plan__label select-plan__label--active" for="select-three-month2">3 month</label>
          </div>
          <div class="dimensional-container">
              <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="twelve-months" id="select-twelve-month2">
              <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-twelve-month2">12 month</label>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer spacer-gap--16"></div>
      <button class="select-plan__submit" type="submit">Try now</button>
  </form>
  <form class="select-plan" action="">
      <div class="select-plan__container">
          <div class="select-plan__range-slider"></div>
          <div class="dimensional-container">
              <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="one-month" id="select-month3">
              <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-month3">1 month</label>
          </div>
          <div class="dimensional-container">
              <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="three-months" id="select-three-month3" checked>
              <label class="select-plan__label select-plan__label--active" for="select-three-month3">3 month</label>
          </div>
          <div class="dimensional-container">
              <input class="select-plan__radio visually-hidden" type="radio" name="select-month" value="twelve-months" id="select-twelve-month3">
              <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-twelve-month3">12 month</label>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer spacer-gap--16"></div>
      <button class="select-plan__submit" type="submit">Try now</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, useful option. Is it possible to make it work for all forms? I mean, right now it switches state only for the first form, even when clicking on the blow ones.

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id` which is not allowed – ids need to be unique throughout the document. This is true whether you end up using my option or not. Edited with unique ids and it's working above.

Comment: I wonder, is it somehow possible to give each of the label:before some speciffic position on the range?